# In PHP how can I collapse the line breaks inside heredoc (here document)?

Tags: php, line-breaks, heredoc

For CLI purpose, I want to **partly** collapse (ignore line break) inside the `heredoc`(here document).

Currently, I use `%%` at the end of the lines which I want to collapse then replace them using `str_replace("%%\n",'', $string);`. But I don't feel quite comfortable with it.

Is there any escape cord or smarter ways to do so?

For example:

```
<?php

$string=<<<EOL
This is a single long line, and it has to be
in one line, though the SideCI thing (as a 
coding regulation) I have to line break.
But this line stays short.
And this line too.
And the backslash such as \
won't work. Nor /
won't work.
My alternative way is to use %%
strings and replace them later.

EOL;

$string .= 'And I don\'t want to do this ';
$string .= 'to merge strings.';

echo str_replace("%%\n",'', $string);
```

I get as below:

```
This is a single long line, and it has to be
in one line, though the SideCI thing (as a 
coding regulation) I have to line break.
But this line stays short.
And this line too.
And the backslash such as \
won't work. Nor /
won't work.
My alternative way is to use strings and replace them later.
And I don't want to do this to merge strings.
```

Any ideas?

---

### Current conclusion (2018/01/17)

> Disable line breaks as a default behavior, and use `BR` tags to line break instead.
>   1. Replace `PHP_EOL`(line breaks) to ''(blank).
>   2. Replace the `BR` tags to `PHP_EOL`.

Sample code:

```
<?php

$string=<<<EOL
This is a single long line, and it has to be
in one line, though the SideCI thing (as a 
coding regulation) I have to line break.<br>
But this line stays short.<br>
And this line too.<br>
My post alternative way was to use %%
chars and replace them later.<br>

EOL;

$string = str_replace(PHP_EOL,'', $string);
$string = str_ireplace(["<br />","<br>","<br/>"], PHP_EOL, $string);

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resort to mangling the HTML standard of using `<br>` tags to say when you do want a line break.  This will feel more intuitive for people used to HTML...

```
$string=<<<EOL
This is a single long line, and it has to be
in one line, though the SideCI thing (as a
coding regulation) I have to line break.
But this line stays short.
And this line too.
And the backslash such as \<br>
won't work. Nor /<br>
won't work.<br>
My alternative way is to use %%<br>
strings and replace them later.

EOL;

$string = str_replace(PHP_EOL,'', $string);
$string = str_ireplace(["<br />","<br>","<br/>"], PHP_EOL, $string);
echo $string;
```

Note the use of `PHP_EOL` to use the correct current encoding of a new line/line break or whatever combination the platform your using has.

Comment: `This will feel more intuitive for people used to HTML...`

I see, deleting all the line breaks first then replacing BR tags to linebreak. That's a neat idea and it is intuitive!
So no escape code there is to un-do linebreak then?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use something like `{nbr}` just because `%%` seems too generic, where `{nbr}` is "no break" and `{...}` is common in templates, That is just an Opinion.

But I would also use a regx instead of str_replace

```
preg_replace('/{nbr}[\r\n]+/', '', $str);
```

This way it matches `\r`, `\r\n`, `\n` and even `\n\n` or Old Mac, Windows, Linux and multiple line ending.

You can see [it here:](https://regex101.com/r/xqznfI/1)

Comment: `because %% seems too generic` Indeed, it is. It used to be `%BR%` before though. But at sometime someone changed the hole specification, think because of his/her laziness to type. And that's why I came up with this uncomfortableness. :_(

Answer (score 0):

This is how I added \n in heredoc

```
<?php
$return_str ='';
$newline_char = "\n";
for($i=0; $i <5 ;$i++)
{

$return_str .= <<<abcd
A random new line $newline_char
abcd;
}
echo $return_str ; 
?>

output: 
A random new line 
A random new line 
A random new line 
A random new line 
A random new line
```